# Gold Ring Calculation

Tags: arithmetic, applications

I have problem with gold ring weight calculation

I have below details to calculate gold ring calculation

```
reference thickness - 1.45mm
reference Width - 6mm
reference Size - 10 (reference diameter for size 10 is 19.84)
reference metal - Platinum
reference weight - 10.10


change thickness - 1.25mm
change Width - 6mm
change Size - 10.5 (reference diameter for size 10 is 19.84)
change metal - Platinum
change weight - 8.75**(I should get this weight)**
```

I want to find the weight per thickness and weight per width and weight per diameter.

I used the below calculation for finding those values

```
WeightPerwidth = reference weight / width 

WeightPerThickness = reference weight / (referenceDiameter + 2* reference thickness)

weightPerDiameter = WeightPerThickness
```

But our client is telling that this is wrong.

So i tried to calculate the percentage difference between two thickness value.

I used the calculation below to find the percentage difference for thickess like between 1.45mm and 1.25mm.

```
Thickness % = ((change thickness - reference thickness)*100)/change thickness

actual weight of thickness bet 1.25 and 1.45 = weightPerThickness * (Thickness % / 100)
```

Main thing is I want to find the percentage diff of thickness in weight .

I dont know how to convert mm value to weight (thickness(mm) to weight(gram) )

Please anyone give me the solution for my problem